# Python Django Mandrill API response 500

Tags: python, django, mandrill

I've been looking at this problem and am stuck in the follwing Python.

https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore

It uses Django which in turn uses Mandrill for emails via the Python package Djrill. It was set up and working but after the SSL cert was updated it was noted that the signup no longer worked but generated a '500 Server Error' message. The log for this event is copied in below.

A new MailChimp account was set up with Mandrill added, I created a new API key and updated the MANDRILL_API_KEY entry. On Mandrill the domain, SPF and DKIM has been verified but it still does not work. I'm not familiar with this software and I'm sure this is simple if you know how. If I look at the Mandrill API logs they are completely blank which makes me think that I'm missing some configuration somewhere, like changing the API key is not enough to change Mandrill account.

This is the page which generates the problem when the form is submitted.

http://music.artbyte.me/musician-sign-up/

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
INFO 2017-01-28 09:07:48,278 connectionpool 86.142.174.63 - POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 Starting new HTTP connection (1): mandrillapp.com
ERROR 2017-01-28 09:07:48,418 base - - - - -" - Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/django/applebytestore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/srv/django/applebytestore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 394, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "./tatianastore/signup.py", line 116, in signup
File "./tatianastore/signup.py", line 103, in create_user
File "./tatianastore/emailer.py", line 22, in mail_store_owner
msg.send()
File "/srv/django/applebytestore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 286, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/srv/django/applebytestore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djrill/mail/backends/djrill.py", line 68, in send_messages
sent = self._send(message)
File "/srv/django/applebytestore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djrill/mail/backends/djrill.py", line 119, in _send
(msg_dict['to'], msg_dict['from_email']))
djrill.exceptions.MandrillAPIError: Mandrill API response 500
Failed to send a message to [{'name': '', 'email': 'n@n.com', 'type': 'to'}], from no-reply@libertymusicstore.net
```

Comment: Try to create a smaller example that we can create without having to set up the entire `LibertyMusicStore` project. What happens if you manually run the `send_email` command, as in the [Djrill readme](https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill)? Note that the docs warn that Djrill has been unmaintained for nearly a year, and recommend django-anymail instead.

Comment: I've moved the project to AnyMail but get the same response, I've removed the two calls to mail_store_owner in tatianastore/emailer.py from tatianastore/creditor.py and tatianastore/emailer.py but still get the same message. Much not be updating as the move to AnyMail should have generated different errors at least. Restarted nginx and removed all .pyc files but still get the same message. I'm not a Python coder so am pretty baffled by this.

Comment: As I said before, I would make sure that your settings are correct by manually running the `send_email` command from the readme. At the moment, it's not clear whether the problem is in your configuration or the repository you've linked to. You don't have an easily reproducable error at the moment, so it's not a great fit for stack overflow.

Comment: You've helped a great deal, I know nothing in the world of Python so anything is a bonus. The move to AnyMail fixed it, I followed the migration steps. Rebooting the server updated everything. I guess that Djrill has not kept up with changes, AnyMail simply works with the migration steps but is almost identical. If you write up, "move to AnyMail" I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The djrill docs say that the project has been inactive since April 2016. They suggest that you use [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) instead.

When you update Python code in production, you need to restart the server (e.g. Apache or gunicorn) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks. AnyMail simply worked after following the migration document. Have to wait 20 more hours before I can award the points.

Comment: Just FYI, 5xx errors from Mandrill often are transient network issues between you and them. You'll probably see them again in the future, and they usually resolve in a few minutes. (But upgrading to Anymail is still a good idea -- it has better error messages than Djrill did, so if this happens again you'll get more details. Anymail/Djrill maintainer.)